# Laravel/snappy not show an image in pdf

Tags: laravel-5

hiii i want to generate pdf of an invoice . pdf is generate but it can't display an image
i use laravel/snappy for window

here is my view file

```
<div>
<img src="{{ asset('image/logo.png') }}" class="pl-3" width="15%" />
<a href="{{ route('pdfview',['download'=>'pdf']) }}">Download PDF</a>
</div>
```

here is my controller

```
if($request->has('download')) {
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdfview')- 
>save(storage_path('invoices/aazsaa.pdf'));
return $pdf->download('userlist.pdf');
}
```

image is shown in view but when i download image is not render

Answer (score 0):

yehh i got the solution of my problem
i use base64 encoder to display an image

here is my view file

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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>
```

i change the src of image in  tag. i just put base64 string of an image instead of path, and it's work